# Работа перегруженного оператора во время инициализации экземпляра класса

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, перегрузка-операторов, операторы

Как перегрузить, например, оператор присваивания таким образом, чтобы он работал во время инициализации экземпляра класса?

```
#include <iostream>`
using namespace std;`

class Matrix
{
private:
    int **Arr;
    int Size;
public:
    Matrix(int SizeOfMatrix);
Matrix operator = (Matrix &);
};

int main()
{
    Matrix A(4);
    Matrix B(4) = A;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
Matrix::Matrix(int SizeOfMatrix)
{
    Size = SizeOfMatrix;
    Arr = new int *[Size];
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        Arr[i] = new int[Size];
        for (int j = 0; j < Size; j++)
            Arr[i][j] = rand() % 50;
    }
}
Matrix Matrix :: operator =(Matrix &A)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Size; j++)
            Arr[i][j] = A.Arr[i][j];
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: @Abyx хорошо, если не таким образом, то каким? форум, вроде бы, для помощи, а не для критики.

Comment: @Abyx хочу, перегрузить оператор присваивания так, чтобы синтаксис в строке `Matrix B(4) = A;` был валидным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прежде всего хотел бы отметить, что данное предложение

```
Matrix B(4) = A;
```

некорректное и не должно компилироваться. Фактически в данном предложении имеется два инициализатора: `4` и `A`.

Но даже если вы правильно напишите

```
Matrix A(4);
Matrix B = A;
```

то здесь вызывается не оператор присваивания, как вы думаете, а конструктор копирования, который определен компилятором неявно, и который просто почленно копирует члены данных объектов.

Когда вы динамически в классе распределяете память, то есть используете указатели, то вы должны определить явно по крайней мере конструктор копирования, копирующий оператор присваивания и деструктор. В противном случае поведение вашей программы может оказаться неопределенным. Например, в результате использования конструктора копирования, созданного компилятором неявно, может оказаться, что два объекта имеют указатели на одну и ту же область памяти, а потому при удалении этих объектов будет осуществлена попытка удалить одну и ту же память дважды.

Ваш класс может выглядеть следующим образом

```
class Matrix
{
private:
    int **Arr;
    size_t Size;
public:
    explicit Matrix( size_t );
    Matrix( const Matrix & );
    ~Matrix();
    Matrix & operator = ( const Matrix & );
};

Matrix::Matrix( size_t SizeOfMatrix ) : Arr( nullptr ), Size ( SizeOfMatrix )
{
    if ( Size )
    {
        Arr = new int *[Size];

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < Size; i++ )
        {
            Arr[i] = new int[Size];
            for ( size_t j = 0; j < Size; j++ ) Arr[i][j] = rand() % 50;
        }
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix( const Matrix &rhs ) : Arr( nullptr ), Size ( rhs.Size )
{
    if ( Size )
    {
        Arr = new int *[Size];

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < Size; i++ )
        {
            Arr[i] = new int[Size];
            for ( size_t j = 0; j < Size; j++ ) Arr[i][j] = rhs.Arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}

Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < Size; i++ ) delete [] Arr[i];
    delete [] Arr;
} 

Matrix & Matrix::operator =( const Matrix &rhs )
{
    if ( this != &rhs )
    {
        int **tmp = nullptr;

        if ( rhs.Size != 0 )
        {
            if ( Size != rhs.Size )
            {
                tmp = new int *[rhs.Size];

                for ( size_t i = 0; i < rhs.Size; i++ )
                {
                    tmp[i] = new int[rhs.Size];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                tmp = Arr;
            }

            for ( size_t i = 0; i < rhs.Size; i++ )
            {
                for ( size_t j = 0; j < rhs.Size; j++ ) tmp[i][j] = rhs.Arr[i][j];
            }
        }

        if ( Size != rhs.Size )
        {
            for ( size_t i = 0; i < Size; i++ ) delete [] Arr[i];
            delete [] Arr;
        }

        Arr = tmp;
        Size = rhs.Size;
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. У меня как раз возникли проблемы с деструктором.

Comment: @АлександрЕфремов Не за что. Мы, начинающие программисты, должны помогать друг другу.:)

Comment: Разумеется, должны. Вы можете рассчитывать на мою помощь.:)

Comment: @АлександрЕфремов O'k.